# Is it possible to have a alpha transparency on a corner of an image with the following requirements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to have a alpha transparency on a corner of an image with the following requirements?

1. I can't use .PNG's to just create the corner removal
2. I need to be able to see the background through the transparency. Meaning it just can't be filled in with one color.
3. The angle I'm needing is just a 90 degree angle from the corner of the image if that helps.
4. Needs to be compatible on at least IE 7,8 and 9. I'm sure if the solution works there it will be compatible on most of the others.

Comment: You can't use PNG but you want alpha transparency? Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use a PNG, why not try using a transparent GIF? ^_^

Comment: Then you might want to consider HTML5's canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial